# Add private GitHub repository in Unity Package Manager

Tags: unity, git

Is there any way available to use a private Git repository directly in a package manager?

Currently, I have made a package and hosted it on GitHub. Now, I want to use it directly from GitHub in Unity. However, this is not accessible, as I have to provide my credentials, but the package manager does not have any credential column.

Comment: [Here is the first result I get](https://forum.unity.com/threads/is-it-possible-to-download-packages-from-my-private-github-repositories.1083584/) when I [search for "unity private github"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=unity+private+github&ia=web). It references [this section of the official Unity documentation explaining how to provide these credentials](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/upm-git.html#Git-SSH). Have you tried the solution described there? What steps did you take and what were the results?